# Congressional District is generally lowercased but because it is in front of a proper noun (Maryland) then 'congressional district' is capitalized?

Tags: grammar, proper-nouns, capitalization

Sentence :Lieutenant Governor Rutherford's State Administration has invested 62 million dollars in the West North Avenue community to demolish and revitalize 100 houses from Milton to Hilton Boulevard, and it has now become a Maryland **Congressional District.**
Question :Is it Maryland congressional district or Maryland Congressional District?

Answer (score 1):

It should be lower case. The article "a" means it's not a unique thing, but one of several or many, so the words "congressional district" are not part of a proper name.

Comment: "Maryland's 1st congressional district encompasses the entire Eastern Shore of Maryland" Wikipedia

Comment: But... oh dear! On a Federal level, the State of Maryland is apportioned into eight Congressional Districts. This determines the number of members to the U.S. House of Representatives from Maryland. Carroll County is apportioned into Congressional Districts one and eight. https://elections.carrollcountymd.gov/Precincts.aspx

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That source also has "Carroll County is comprised of two Legislative Districts and one Sub-district. The districts are 4 and 5 and the sub-district is 9A. ", which capitalizes "Sub-district", and then doesn't. I don't think it's reliable.

Comment: I think it might be a style issue.